# PHP duplicated field multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I am using this while loop in order to echo some data:

```
$arr = array(); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $tip= $row["tip"]; 
    $name= $row["name"];
    $qty= $row["qty"];
    $arr = "\n".$tip. "" .$qty."x " .$name; 
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr);
    echo "</pre>";
 }
```

And getting those results:

```
Food 1x Hambuger
Food 1x Pizza
Food 1x Milk
Food 1x Wine
Sports 2x Shirt
Sports 1x Gloves
Sports 1x Shoes
```

However, this is my **expected result**:

```
Food
1x Hambuger
1x Pizza
1x Milk
1x Wine
Sports
2x Shirt
1x Gloves
1x Shoes
```

Should be use array unique?

Thanks!

Comment: Before assigning `$row["tip"]` to `$tip`, see if they are equal.  If not, output `$row["tip"]` (and a newline), and then assign to `$tip`.  If they are, don't output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better extract the data differently - This way it will work even if the `tip` is not ordered (AKA food, sports and then food again).

Consider:

```
$arr = array(); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $arr[$row["tip"]][] = $row["qty"] . "x " . $row["name"];
}
foreach($arr as $tip => $values) {
    echo $tip . PHP_EOL;
    foreach($values as $e) {
        echo $e . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

**Edited**:

as you want it outside use:

```
$arr = array(); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $arr[$row["tip"]][] = $row["qty"] . "x " . $row["name"];
}
$res = array(); // init empty array for result
foreach($arr as $tip => $values) {
    $res[] = $tip;
    $res = array_merge($res, $e)
}

echo implode("\n", $res);
```

Now `$res` is available outside the loop

Comment: how can I use $tip and $e  outside foreach loop?

Comment: They are inner var of the loop scope - so you cannot. What do you need them for? why not use them in the foreach loop? You can get them also from the `$arr` var outside the loop if you really need to

Comment: I need to pass this result into onesignal array. 

$fields = array(
 'data' => array("array" => "".$result_of_your_array.""),
 'priority' => 10 
 );

Comment: Updated the answer to get the result outside the loop

Comment: get this error:
Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array

$e variable seems not declared:

Comment: I resolved, but don't know if is a good way or not.

$res = array(); // init empty array for result
foreach($arr as $tip => $values) {
    $res[] = $tip;  

foreach($values as $e) {
     $res[] = $e;
 }

}

echo implode("\n", $res);